# En Colombia, ¿qué quiere decir "tenaz"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, colombia

Mis amigos colombianos usan mucho el adjetivo ***tenaz***:

> Uuuuy, el viaje estuvo *tenaz*: apenas llegamos, nos robaron las maletas.
>
> Este chico es un estudiante *tenaz*.

Yo lo entiendo como "complicado", "difícil" (primer ejemplo) pero también como "bueno", "habilidoso" (segundo ejemplo).

Pero ninguna de esas acepciones las recoge la RAE:

> [**tenaz**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZS8ViZp)
>   *Del lat. tenax, -ācis.*
>   1. adj. Que se pega, ase o prende a una cosa, y es dificultoso de separar.
>   2. adj. Que opone mucha resistencia a romperse o deformarse.
>   3. adj. Firme, porfiado y pertinaz en un propósito.

Así que un poco de búsqueda me llevó a definiciones como

> -difícil; en particular, difícil de soportar. <sup>[Jergas de habla hispana](http://www.jergasdehablahispana.org/?pais=Colombia&palabra=tenaz&tipobusqueda=1)</sup>
>
> -Significa como una persona, animal u objeto que es muy hagil [sic] en algo, o muy bueno en algo, si es en un Objeto se podria decir en algun tipo de nivel de un Juego (...). <sup>[Yahoo respuestas](https://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110822191005AAhVF9o)</sup>

Así que, ¿podría algún colombiano darnos información al respecto? Mi querido [Bogotalogo](https://www.scribd.com/doc/94635822/Bogotalogo-Version-Digital) no contiene información al respecto.

Comment: Las acepciones de la RAE son las que yo conozco para _tenaz_. Me resulta curioso que la tercera acepción sea la genérica, las otras dos se pueden derivar: firme y pertinaz en el propósito de no romperse o deformarse, y firme y pertinaz en el propósito de pegarse a algo y no separarse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La palabra *tenaz* en Colombia ha adoptado significados parecidos a la palabra *berraco* ([sí, con **b**. Léase este artículo para más ilustración](http://www.semana.com/opinion/articulo/verraco-berraco/10346-3)) que tiene el sentido de **el mejor, el as, el superior, el furioso, lo increíble, lo fascinante, fuerte, valiente o cualquier otra cosa que uno quiera decir**. No en todos los casos aplica teniendo *berraco* un sentido más amplio y significados que tenaz no tiene.

Aunque siendo *berraco* ampliamente utilizada en toda Colombia es casi 'propiedad' de los habitantes de los departamentos de Antioquia, Caldas, Risaralda y Quindío (o Paisas entre los cuales me cuento) por lo que en muchas otras regiones es reemplazada por "tenaz".

Principalmente en Bogotá *tenaz* tiene sentido casi siempre de **difícil**, *fregado* o *sobado*. (Estas dos últimas palabras NO tienen tal significado en la RAE pero sí en Bogotá y sus alrededores)

Ejemplos de su uso y su traducción al español podrían ser los siguientes:

> Uy, qué frío tan tenaz/berraco = Está haciendo mucho frío, ¿cierto?
>
> ... es un estudiante tenaz / ... es un berraco pa' estudiar  = ... es un estudiante sobresaliente/excepcional.
>
> Qué trabajo tan tenaz/berraco = Este trabajo está muy difícil.
>
> La película Avengers estuvo tenaz = La película Los Vengadores estuvo buenísima.
>
> Mariana Pajón/Rigoneitor es tenaz = Mariana Pajon/Rigoberto Urán es una/un ciclista increible.

Si se me ocurren más ejemplos los iré adicionando, pero creo que con estos hay suficiente ilustración.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por contestar. Nótese que ser el único colombiano que conozco en este sitio no te obliga a contestar todo lo que sea relativo a Colombia, incluso aunque te lo pida en comentarios jaja ;) Pero siempre que lo hagas, estaremos encantados y eternamente agradecidos.

Comment: Amigo @fedorqui, siempre contribuyo con gusto y si es con respecto a la tierrita, mucho más. Es solo que he estado escaso de tiempo

Comment: Fantástica respuesta. Para concretar, mis amigos son bogotanos, por lo que la acepción que intuía es la de _difícil_. ¡Interesantísimo que _berraco_ (palabra que ya conocía por habérsela oído) sea sinónimo! En España _sobado_ lo usamos para referirnos a algo muy manido, o incluso a alguien que está manoseando a otro: _tu novio te está sobando mucho últimamente_. Y bueno, luego tenemos el [sobao](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobao), que es una especie de magdalena buenísima.

Answer (score 3):

Acabo de ver vuestra inquietud. Soy bogotano, 70 años.
La palabra **tenaz** sin duda descubre nuestra nacionalidad cuando la usamos fuera de nuestro país.

Denota  dificultad para hacer algo o cuando algo es de grado sumo.

Ej: Este trabajo está muy tenaz.
Ej: Qué aguacero tan tenaz

Answer (score 2):

Hay distintas posibles definiciones según el contexto:

1. Algo difícil de lograr.
2. Mensaje con contenido que nos pone nerviosos. *Esa película estuvo tenaz*.
3. Situación de riesgo. *Es tenaz cruzar ese río en esta embarcación*.
4. En general se puede tomar como sinónimo de: duro, difícil, complicado, potente, osado, etc.

Comment: Esta respuesta ganaría un poco si explicases de dónde provienen esas definiciones y cómo aplican al caso particular de Colombia, que es el ámbito de la pregunta. Visita las secciones de [tour] y [help] para aprender más sobre la filosofía de los stacks si lo necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Yo suelo utilizar frecuentemente la palabra "tenaz" para describir una situación o evento terrible y que por otra parte, nada tiene que ver con la definición oficial que aparece en el diccionario. También se emplea como sinónimo de “duro”, y que en esta ocasión, sí tiene relación con la segunda definición, que dice, que es difícil de deformarse o inflexible.

- Amigo: Me quedé sin plata.
- Yo: Tenaz… (terrible, qué duro!).
- Me parece tenaz la situación del país. (dura la situación).
- Esa persona es muy tenaz. (Persona que se enfrenta a todos los problemas, no importa la dificultad que estos conlleven).

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con el *Diccionario de americanismos*, [**tenaz**](https://www.asale.org/damer/tenaz) en Colombia significa:

> I. 1. adj. Co, Ec. Referido a situación o cosa, difícil o complicada. pop.
>
> II.   1.  adj. Co. Referido a situación cosa, increíble. pop.